# shuffling with random seed throws error with sh

Tags: bash, shuffle

I am trying to run shuf with a fixed seed. I save the following commands in `run.sh` and run `sh run.sh`:

```
function get_seeded_random() {
  seed="$1"
  openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -pass pass:"$seed" -nosalt \
    </dev/zero 2>/dev/null
}
shuf -i1-100 --random-source=<(get_seeded_random 42)
```

but I get:

```
~: sh run.sh
shuf: '<(get_seeded_random 42)': No such file or directory
```

It works for  `sort` but not sure why it is throwing error for `shuf`. Also `source run.sh` works with no error.

Comment: You do not use `bash`.

Comment: Even without `!/bin/bash` it throws the same error.

Comment: You use `sh` and not `bash`.

Comment: What is wrong with using `sh`?

Comment: You use `bash` code in a `sh` script. Usually `sh` does not know `<(...)`.

Comment: Oh OK. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Btw.: `shuf` expects a file name after `--random-source=`.

Comment: `<(get_seeded_random 42)` is a *Process Substitution* and is not part of POSIX shell. It is a bashism for practical purposes.

Comment: Then why does it work with `sort` and not with `shuf`?